# JSON prints just one line

Tags: mysql, json, perl

I am trying to recieve data from database in JSON format as you see from following code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI;
use JSON;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:hostname=localhost:3306;database=dbname','dbuser','dbpass') or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do("set names utf8");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{select NAME, ID from CUSTOMER;}) or die;
$dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() or die $sth->errstr;    

my$json={};
    while(my@customer = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
        $json->{"value"} = $customer[0];
        $json->{"id"} = "$customer[1]";
    }
print JSON::to_json($json);
```

Printed output is just one customer: {"value":"customer_name","id":"666"}. I need to get all the customers, not just the only one. How do I do that? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your json is a hash reference, you keep over writing your element every time. do something like (untested)

```
my $json=[];
while(my @customer = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    push @{$json}, {value => $customer[0], id => $customer[1]};
}
print JSON::to_json($json);
```

Comment: Re: "_As your json is a hash reference_" -- those assignments `= ...` just overwrite, regardless of what it is

Comment: Or just do `$json = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({})`